# How do I put the result of call into a variable?

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to use another batch file called `uppercase.bat` to convert an existing string to uppercase.

```
@echo off
set /p TitleID=Enter the ID of the title you want to download. 
set /p GameName=What is the name of the game you are trying to download? 

:Execute
java -jar JNUSTool.jar %TitleID% -dlEncrypted
pause

:Change_to_uppercase 
call %~dp0\uppercase.bat %TitleID%

:Rename
echo Renaming to %GameName%...
rename "%~dp0temp_%UpperTitleID%" "%~dp0%GameName%"
pause
```

`uppercase.bat` does this:

```
@ECHO OFF
SET STRING=%1
IF [%STRING%]==[] GOTO:EOF
SET STRING=%STRING:a=A%
SET STRING=%STRING:b=B%
SET STRING=%STRING:c=C%
SET STRING=%STRING:d=D%
SET STRING=%STRING:e=E%
SET STRING=%STRING:f=F%
SET STRING=%STRING:g=G%
SET STRING=%STRING:h=H%
SET STRING=%STRING:i=I%
SET STRING=%STRING:j=J%
SET STRING=%STRING:k=K%
SET STRING=%STRING:l=L%
SET STRING=%STRING:m=M%
SET STRING=%STRING:n=N%
SET STRING=%STRING:o=O%
SET STRING=%STRING:p=P%
SET STRING=%STRING:q=Q%
SET STRING=%STRING:r=R%
SET STRING=%STRING:s=S%
SET STRING=%STRING:t=T%
SET STRING=%STRING:u=U%
SET STRING=%STRING:v=V%
SET STRING=%STRING:w=W%
SET STRING=%STRING:x=X%
SET STRING=%STRING:y=Y%
SET STRING=%STRING:z=Z%
ECHO %STRING%
```

That's about it. The editor wants me to add more details, but that's all I can give.

Comment: Fine. And what is your question?

Comment: Without knowing what your uppercase.bat does it's difficult to help. If the other batch sets the var `UpperTitleID` there should be no problem.

Comment: Just letting you know, I edited my post, I don't know If it tells you that, so I posted this comment.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't pass the content of the var to the called batch, but indirectly the name of the var. Since the called batch shares the same environment it can modify the variable. So use this sample `upperCase.bat`

```
@Echo off&SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
Set "ToUpper=!%~1!"
For %%U In (A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z) Do (
  Set "ToUpper=!ToUpper:%%U=%%U!"
)
Endlocal&Set "%~1=%ToUpper%"
```

Sample output:

```
> Set "TitleID=this is all lower case"

> upperCase.bat TitleID

> Set Tit
TitleID=THIS IS ALL LOWER CASE
```

Comment: Just letting you know, I edited my post, I don't know If it tells you that, so I posted this comment.

Answer (score 0):

Your external batch file will return the result in the variable `string`, so all yo need to do is to assign that value to `UpperTitleID` - or change `UpperTitleID` to `string` when you want to use it in the rename command.

```
set "UpperTitleID=%string%"
```

The syntax `SET "var=value"` (where value may be empty) is used to ensure that any stray trailing spaces are NOT included in the value assigned. `set /a` can safely be used "quoteless".

Note that the `%~dp0\` in `call %~dp0\uppercase.bat` is probably redundant. Windows will find `uppercase.bat` if it is in the current directory or in any directory specified on the `path` (for instance, in your batch-file directory, if you've included you batch-file directory in your `path`)

`Rename` is a poor name for a label because it is a keyword.

Comment: I put %~dp0 there because I plan on using this batch file in the future with other computers, and I don't to go and rename it. (of course, in that example it doesn't apply, but whatever.)

Answer (score 0):

`%~dp0` expands to path of batch file always ending with a backslash. Therefore don't specify an additional backslash after this string although it works because Windows removes the second backslash later.

It is also recommended to double quote the entire string in case of current batch file path contains for example a space character, i.e. use

```
call "%~dp0uppercase.bat" %TitleID%
```

The string assigned to environment variable `TitleID` is not quoted and therefore can't contain a space character or another character with special meaning on command line on parsing it to batch file `uppercase.bat`.

I suggest to embed code of `uppercase.bat` into your batch file.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

echo/
echo Enter the ID of the title you want to download.
echo/
set "TitleID="

:TitlePrompt
set /P "TitleID=Title: "
if not defined TitleId goto TitlePrompt
set "TitleId=!TitleId:"=!"
if not defined TitleId goto TitlePrompt

echo/
echo What is the name of the game you are trying to download?
echo/
set "GameName="

:GamePrompt
set /P "GameName=Game:  "
if not defined GameName goto GamePrompt
set "GameName=!GameName:"=!"
if not defined GameName goto GamePrompt

echo/
java.exe -jar "%~dp0JNUSTool.jar" "!TitleID!" -dlEncrypted

for %%U in (A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z) do set "TitleID=!TitleID:%%U=%%U!"

echo Renaming to !GameName! ...
ren "%~dp0temp_!TitleID!" "!GameName!"

endlocal
```

**Note:** The new name of a file being renamed must be specified without path or rename fails.

The batch code above checks if user has really entered anything at all and removes double quotes from entered string and checking once again if the remaining entered string has a length greater 0.

The batch code should be further improved to remove from entered title and game name all characters which are not acceptable in a file name like `:\/<>|` and others.

`echo/` outputs just a blank line as it can be seen on running this batch file from within a command prompt window which is preferred for testing a batch file in development to see errors output by Windows command interpreter in case of having made a syntax error.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `ren /?` or `rename /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`